# Integral of symmetric function

Tags: integration, symmetry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})$ for every $n$-permutation $\sigma$, and suppose that $I=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1\dots dx_n$ is finite.

**Conjecture.** There is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $n!$ disjoint sets $S_1,\dots,S_{n!}$ such that 
$$
  I=n!\int_{S_1}f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1\dots dx_n \, .
$$
I would like to receive feedback on this conjecture (proof or counterexample) as well as a description of the sets $S_i$.

Comment: I think it would be good to give some motivation; why do you think this is true? Can you describe the sets $S_i$ in some simple cases (for example $f$ radial)?

Comment: Start with $n=2$. You may see a candidate for $S_1$, $S_2$ right away. To be fair, the hypothesis "disjoint" has to be slightly modified to "they intersect only at boundary points" or similar.  Once you found for $n=2$, try $n=3$.